# Why SharePoint Assemblies are downloadable from vti_bin of O365 Tenant?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I was wondering is it a safe practice from Microsoft to allow assemblies to be downloaded by client from _vti_bin folder?

For example, anyone can download SharePoint.Dll directly by browsing to following url:

https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/microsoft.sharepoint.dll

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a little bit safer than the standard SharePoint/IIS configuration of having Handler Mappings with Execute rights enabled.